# Logback : enable class on specific appender et disable it on the others

Tags: java, logging, logback, spring-logback

A specific class from a dependency produces too much logs, so I'm trying to store them in a specific file to avoid pollution of the other ones.

here's my logback-spring.xml file :

```xml
<configuration debug="true">

<!-- appenders declaration --> 

    <logger
        name="org.apache.james.protocols.netty.BasicChannelUpstreamHandler"
        level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FileConnections" />
    </logger>


    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FileInf" /> <!-- ThresholdFilter Info -->
        <appender-ref ref="FileErr" /> <!-- ThresholdFilter Error -->
        <appender-ref ref="FileTra" /> <!-- ThresholdFilter Trace -->
        <appender-ref ref="JsonInf" /> <!-- Json formater -->
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />  <!-- Console output -->
    </root>


</configuration>
```

This code does redirect all the BasicChannelUpstreamHandler logs to my FileConnections appender but there is still logs fromm this class in other appenders.

Is there a way to disable BasicChannelUpstreamHandler logs on all the other appenders ?

Comment: You need to set the additivity flag to false. 
 `<logger
        name="org.apache.james.protocols.netty.BasicChannelUpstreamHandler"
        level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FileConnections" />
    </logger>`.

Comment: It works, thank you ! Can you put it as a Reply so I can mark it as the resolution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **additivity** flag to **false** as shown below.

```
<logger name="org.apache.james.protocols.netty.BasicChannelUpstreamH‌​andler" level="INFO" additivity="false"> 
    <appender-ref ref="FileConnections" /> 
</logger>
```